Android Studio terminal dart commands opening an empty file
Problem Has Been Fixed
As @julemand101 said, I should not have installed Dart SDK seperately because it is included with the Flutter SDK. Here's what I done to fix the issue:

I completely removed the Dart SDK;
Made Android Studio > settings > languages and frameworks > dart : dart SDK path point to the Dart SDK included in Flutter SDK;
I was still having problems because the empty file called "Dart" found in C:/Windows/System32 so I moved that to a temporary folder elsewhere in the system;
I also found an empty file called "Flutter" in C:/Windows/System32 so I also moved this to the temporary folder that I had put the dart file in.

And that was it - problem solved!
Original Question Below....
Author's Note
I might sound like I know what I'm talking about here, but I can assure you it mostly thanks to extensive use of ChatGPT to try and diagnose and fix the issue :) I've tried to be as detailed as I can but please let me know if you need any more information.
Description
I have a new PC and am in the process of setting up Android Studio to work with Flutter and Dart. I'm encountering difficulties running Dart commands in the terminal within Android Studio. Despite having installed the Dart SDK and configured the PATH environment variable, whenever I attempt to run a Dart command (e.g., dart --version), I get a new window asking me which application I would like to use to open the file in. The file it is trying to open is an empty file.
Background

I have downloaded Flutter SDK which seems to work fine and is saved to C:\Users\Acer\Coding\flutter_windows_3.19.5-stable\flutter. Flutter commands don't work in the terminal but I don't believe that they should at this point - however I can start a new Flutter project (generated) and run that on an emulator just fine.

I have downloaded the Dart SDK which is saved to C:\tools\dart-sdk.

I've updated the PATH environment variable to include the Dart SDK directory (C:\tools\dart-sdk).

Android Studio > settings > tools > terminal : start directory points to C:\Users\Acer\StudioProjects\fluttersdkdone.

Android Studio > settings > languages and frameworks > dart : dart SDK path points to C:\Users\Acer\Coding\flutter_windows_3.19.5-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk.

Android Studio > settings > languages and frameworks > dart : dart SDK path points to C:\Users\Acer\Coding\flutter_windows_3.19.5-stable\flutter.

I can access dart commands by specifying the exact location of with a command, ie. "C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart --version" returns the dart version as expected.


Notes
When I run any dart command and I get the window which pops up asking me which application I would like to use....I have tried opening it in different applications. Opening it on wordpad and notepad just opens up as empty. When I open it in a web browser, the address is pointing to C:/Windows/System32/dart (which when I copy and paste directly comes out as "file:///C:/Windows/System32/dart"). I have located this file in file explorer where I have found a file called "dart" which appears to be empty. It has a file size of "0 bytes" and is of the type "file". When I try to open this file from file explorer, the same window pops up asking which application I would like to use to open the file - so it appears to me that when I am running dart commands in Android Studio terminal it is trying to open this file.
I have tried restarting Android Studio and restarting machine many times between different steps.
I have tried finding similar issues in forums.
I have tried troubleshooting with ChatGPT.
I have tried renaming the file to see how that affects terminal commands and it makes it throw an error.
I Have Tried setting Android Studio > settings > languages and frameworks > dart > dart SDK path to "C:\tools\dart-sdk". When I reboot Android Studio, it resets it back to "C:\Users\Acer\Coding\flutter_windows_3.19.5-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk" ....however, "C:\tools\dart-sdk" is then available from the dropdown list of Dart SDK paths. I have clicked on the "..." button next to the dropdown list to see if i can delete one of these paths from the list so that only the other remains but when I click on the "delete" button it asks "Are you sure you want to delete the folder "dart-sdk"?" which I am concerned might delete the whole folder rather than just deleting it from the list of dart sdk paths.
Specs and Versions

Windows 10: Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2808 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processor(s)

Dart SDK version: 3.3.3 (stable) (Tue Mar 26 14:21:33 2024 +0000) on "windows_x64"

Flutter version 3.19.5.

Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11668458, built on April 4, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0--11185874 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 6
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
Dart (232.10313)
io.flutter (78.4.1)



If doing Flutter, you should not install Dart since it comes with Flutter and it is important to use the exact version of Dart which your Flutter version expect.

Thanks very much julemand101 - what an oversight on my behalf! 20 or so hours in to trying to solve this before I asked for help and you provided such a simple fix :D

No problem. I have added an answer you can accept. Please just correct it if I am missing some details. :)

There were too many pending edits on stack overflow for me to post an edit to your answer so I posted a new answer instead. I was originally looking to see if there is a way to post an "answer" but I couldn't find the button for some reason, hence why I put it as an edit to my original question.
Thanks so much for your help!!

The issue of the terminal seemingly opening an empty file when running Dart (or Flutter) commands was due to the fact that there was an empty file called Dart (and another called Flutter) in my System32 folder. I moved these files to a new folder which I created in a different location on the system. This fixed the issue and so I deleted the new folder with the empty Dart and Flutter files inside it. Problem solved.
Additionally, Dart SDK should not have been downloaded separately because there is a Dart SDK included within the Flutter SDK. So I deleted the separately installed Dart SDK with all the files inside it. After that, I pointed the Dart SDK settings inside Android Studio IDE to the Dart SDK which is nested inside the Flutter SDK.
These 2 steps fixed all problems I was having.
